# Firebird Windows Trusted logging in and assigning roles

Tags: windows, firebird, roles, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird 2.5 and want to log on with Windows Trusted authentication which works fine. However I want each windows user to be allocated a specific role for the database they are logging into. I have defined my roles in the database but don't know how to allocate the role to the windows user. I thought if I added a user with the same windows name in the security database and assigned them a role that would work, but apparently not. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The only way in Firebird 2.5 and earlier to use a role, is to explicitly specify it on connect in the `isc_dpb_sql_role_name` connection property (or equivalent), assuming that the user has been granted the role. There is one exception introduced in Firebird 2.5, and that is 'auto admin mapping' which automatically enables the `RDB$ADMIN` role for administrator users.

In Firebird 3 you can create custom mappings which allow you to map specific users to roles. See [Mapping of Users to Objects](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-security-mapping). This documentation suggests it is also possible to map user groups derived from trusted auth to roles or users, but this isn't clearly documented, so I'm not exactly sure how it works.

Firebird 4 will introduce default roles for users, which can be granted as a default role to that user. Default roles will always be enabled for a user.